# Parity Violation In The Weak Force

Tags: symmetry, weak-interaction, parity

I am having some trouble understanding parity violation in the weak interaction. Specifically, I have been reading about the 1956 Wu Experiment. From what I understand, it is the anisotropic distribution of electrons that implies parity violation. Why, however, is this necessarily true. By placing the atom in a magnetic field, aren't you placing a "preferred" direction on the system, meaning the direction of emission for the electrons and antineutrinos may also have some correlation to this direction. Furthermore, under parity inversion, wouldn't the direction of this field flip, causing the nuclear spin to flip orientation, leading the experiment to proceed unchanged (the direction of emission would also flip, as expected). I'm sure I am missing something, but I can't figure out what the crucial point is.

Comment: Yes, there will be a preferred direction, so that you only have cylindrical symmetry. If there is parity symmetry, however, the emission pattern in North pole will be the same as the South pole, so net emission will be symmetric across the equatorial plane. The experiment showed that there is a difference, and thus there is a violation of parity symmetry.